# parasitic battery drain on my 98 jeep cherokee

Tags: battery, battery-drain

I have an amp draw of .85 tested from my negative battery cable on one lead and the neg. post on the other lead of my multimeter, I have removed every single fuse and relay and unplugged every single connection I can find and it will not drop.  Battery is draining every few days, new battery, new alternator, removed the wires from the starter and the meter will not drop.  Nothing aftermarket except the radio which I have also unplugged. Anyone have any suggestions? losing my mind

Comment: There is a connection that is still made : coutesy lights or interior light or underhood light or glovebox light etc Really have to check the detail now. Only needs one wire that you have missed so far...

Comment: Did you disconnect alternator?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Also, there are most likely two fuse boxes, one in the cabin and one underhood. Just making sure you're aware.

Answer (score 1):

You method is sound, first you need to make sure you've found all the fuses. I don't know the Cherokee, but fortunately the [internet does](https://fuse-box.info/jeep/jeep-cherokee-xj-1997-2001-fuses-and-relays) and apparently there's a passenger as well as an engine bay fuse box. You'll probably find your drain is a shorted courtesy light or something like that in the end.

The alternator is possible source of battery drains, you should try disconnecting it electrically to see if that solves the issue.

If you have all the fuses out plus the alternator disconnected and there's still a drain then it's being caused by a short that is between the battery and the fuse boxes, because if you have the fuses out it can't be past the fuses. You would have to trace the wiring from the positive battery terminal to the fuse boxes and see if you can find it.